# When soaking chickpeas (garbanzo beans), do I discard floaters?

Tags: chickpeas

When I put my dried chickpeas in water to soak, some of them float. Should I throw these ones away, or are they okay?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Boy is THAT ever controversial. It seems that everybody has a theory as to why some beans float while most do not. The most common answer is that the "floaters" are older, and less hydrated to begin with. Some people insist that some beans float because worms have gotten into them. Hogwash, ignore those comments. The bottom line is that "floaters" are perfectly safe, and there is nothing "icky" about them, although they *may* take longer to fully cook. So, it becomes a matter of personal choice. If it's important to you that *all* of your chickpeas cook to *exactly* the same degree of tenderness, throw them out. If you don't mind a *slightly* (and I do mean *slightly*) chewier bean here and there, keep them. Personally, I keep them.

Welcome to Seasoned Advice by the way, great first question!

Comment: I actually prefer a bit of texture variety, so in the future I'll definitely keep the floaters then. Thanks for the welcome. :)

Comment: Ever so glad I could help. I hope you stick around!